# User Folder Shows Under Network Locations in This PC on Windows 10

Tags: windows, networking, windows-10, shared-folders

So I just noticed that when that my user folder (c:/Users/) shows up under network locations in This PC / My Computer.

I never shared this folder, for some reason I found sharing was enabled for for c:/users. In addition my user folder was mounted as a network drive Z. I disabled sharing for this folder, and dismounted it, and no other shares are showing in Computer Management - however it still shows under Network Locations section.

Does anyone know why did it appear there in the first place?

And how to remove it from there?

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mq23u.png]

Comment: Go to `Control Panel > Network and Sharing Center`. From the left pane click `Change advance sharing settings`. Under `All networks select `All Networks` and turn off `Public folder sharing`.

Comment: Or Open `Network & Internet Settings`. Click `Sharing Options` under `Change your Network Settings`. Expand `All Networks` and `Turn off Public Folder Sharing`.

Comment: Thanks, I tried that, turned off all possible sharing options but it still shows.

Answer (score 0):

Right click the folder in its original location and go to properties. Go to sharing tab and go to advanced sharing and disable it from there. If it's already disabled, try enabling it from there, click ok and so on. Then follow the steps again to disable it and see if this helps.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that when you share folder in Windows, all other folders that are in the path of that folder are shared as well. I have shared folder under `My Documents` and all folders in that path are shared, full recursive share.

But when I share `C:\test` folder, I can access only that folder from other machines on the network.

Answer (score 0):

I happened onto a similar problem and I found a workaround (kinda). I was trying to share a folder in MyDocument and everytime the folder Users was shown under Network, which was dangerous. Plus going through the full route from Users to the folder every time was really annoying. I just wanted that one specific folder, so i begun testing. Turns out if you use the advanced sharing tool (properties > Sharing > Advanced Sharing Options or right-click "Grant access to") on a folder under USERS, it shares the WHOLE root folder (C:/USERS). For showing that folder and that folder ONLY, you have to share it from the folder properties > Sharing > Share (just above the advanced option). For any folder outside Users i think you can safely use any of these options as they both behaved the same way. When i tested only the selected folders where shared (I.e. any folder under Program Files, Windows, folders in another drive... etc).

To answer the OP's question, I can't claim the following because I don't really know nor can test it rn, but I suspect that Users is shared as a default from install or when you configure sharing files over network for the first time. I say this because the Users folder is showing rn on another laptop I have. I remember configuring it to be visible on lan but I don't remember sharing any folder, just as the OP. That, or for whatever reason the OP or I shared a folder under users and the whole folder was shared since. Unsharing C:/Users to hide it from Network works as intended, but in my case turning off sharing files without unsharing the folder worked as well, unlike OP's, so I don't know about that.

In any case, I think the advanced sharing tool seems to be hard-coded to share from C:/Users when detected on the folder's path, so use the regular option or put the folder to be shared outside of Users if you don't want this to happen.